# C# WPF Combobox TextElement.Foreground Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, binding

I wish to link the `TextElement.Foreground` property of my combo box to the variable : `"ALV_COULEUR"` of my object : `"tValeur"`.

I note in output that it does not find variable ALV_COULEUR ...

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'ALV_COULEUR' property not found on 'object' ''Attribut'
>   (HashCode=35307513)'. BindingExpression:Path=ALV_COULEUR;
>   DataItem='Attribut' (HashCode=35307513); target element is 'ComboBox'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush')

The linked object is the value and not the 'Attribut' ...

It is not possible to make a binding in this case?

Thanks!

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          TextElement.Foreground="{Binding ALV_COULEUR, Converter={StaticResource IntToBrushConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding tValeur, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValuePath="ALV_ID" DisplayMemberPath="ALV_VALEUR"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ATT_VALEUR, Converter={StaticResource StringToIntConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</ComboBox>
```

EDIT :

my classes :

```
public class Attribut
{
    public int                      ATT_ID          { get; set; }
    public string                   ATT_LIBELLE     { get; set; }

    public List<ValeurAttribut>     tValeur         { get; set; }
}

public class ValeurAttribut
{
    public int      ALV_ID      { get; set; }
    public string   ALV_VALEUR  { get; set; }
    public int      ALV_COULEUR { get; set; }
}
```

DataContext : `DataGrid` linked to an `ObservableCollection<Attribut>()`

Comment: It fails because your data context is not right.  Can you show how the data context is provided for your ComboBox (and parent objects)?

Comment: @JamesHarcourt I edited the post with the description of the classes

Comment: @WDKyle: Why isn't the ALV_COULEUR property defined in the Attribut class? Or do you want a different colour for each item in the ComboBox?

Comment: @mm8: Yes, for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an `ItemTemplate` with a `TextBlock` and bind its `Foreground` property to your `ALV_COULEUR` source property. Also bind the T`extBlock.Foreground` to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          TextBlock.Foreground="{Binding SelectedItem.ALV_COULEUR, Converter={StaticResource IntToBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
          ItemsSource="{Binding tValeur, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValuePath="ALV_ID" DisplayMemberPath="ALV_VALEUR"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ATT_VALEUR, Converter={StaticResource StringToIntConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ALV_VALEUR}" Foreground="{Binding ALV_COULEUR, Converter={StaticResource IntToBrushConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I have already tested but it does not work because my combobox is
editable. So I can not grab anything if I put a textblock.

Comment: I don't follow. You can copy the text of the selected item, can't you? This approach should work just fine for editable ComboBoxes. Did you even try it?

Comment: Yes, I did not speak well. It works for selectable items but for the selected item which is a textbox, it keeps the color black. With TextElement.Foreground everything is well colored.

Comment: Good ! So obliged to manage this separately for the selected item and the others items? thanks :)

Comment: I just realized that when typing text, the color returns to black :(

Comment: Yes, until an item is selected. What colour do you expect for an item that is not in the list...? There is obviously no ALV_COULEUR for an unexisting ValeurAttribut.